# (Beautiful soap4, )AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'

Tags: python, web, web-scraping, python-requests

Blog: Analyzing IMDb’s Top 250 movies: Part 1; Let scrape some data

For detailed info: https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/analyzing-imdbs-top-250-movies-part-1-let-scrape-some-data-a422adc3eb8d

The problem is that whenever I want to retrieve the individual page links which are in IMDb’s Top 250 movies getting an error:`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'` this means what I understand that it doesn't have the required class names or an element we are looking for in an HTML. But HTML consists of the class name which I passed.
I'm Implementing the same as the blog but I'm not able to retrieve individual movie and scrape the data.
Here is the code same as in the blog:

```
import requests                 # Simpler HTTP requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup   # Python package for pulling data out of HTML and XML files
import pandas as pd             # Python package for data manipulation and analysis
import re                       # regular expressions
import json                     # Python package used to work with JSON data
from tqdm import tqdm           # python for displaying progressbar 
from datetime import datetime

url = 'https://www.imdb.com/chart/top'
url_text = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(url_text, 'html.parser'
template = 'https://www.imdb.com%s'
title_links = [template % a.attrs.get('href') for a in url_soup.select( 'td.titleColumn a' )]

movie_name = (page_soup.find("div",{ "class":"title_wrapper" }).get_text( strip=True ).split('|')[0]).split('(')[0]
```

Comment: Your code does not run, it seems to be missing some variable declarations, like `url_soup` and `page_soup`

Answer (score 2):

The data you need can be easily found in `td` tag with class name `titleColumn`. You can extract the Movie names and links from there.

Here I am showing the Top 10 Movies. You can modify this code to suit your requirement.

```
import requests
import bs4 as bs

url = "https://www.imdb.com/chart/top"
response = requests.get(url)
html = response.text
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

t = soup.findAll('td', class_='titleColumn')
for i in range(10):
    a_tag = t[i].find('a')
    link = 'https://www.imdb.com/' + a_tag['href']
    title = a_tag.text

    print(f'Link: {link}\nMovie: {title}\n')
```

```
Sample Output:

Link: https://www.imdb.com//title/tt0111161/
Movie: The Shawshank Redemption

Link: https://www.imdb.com//title/tt0068646/
Movie: The Godfather

Link: https://www.imdb.com//title/tt0071562/
Movie: The Godfather: Part II

Link: https://www.imdb.com//title/tt0468569/
Movie: The Dark Knight
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a much easier way to get the title. Each page has a `<title>` element with exactly the information you need:

```py
import requests                 # Simpler HTTP requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup   # Python package for pulling data out of HTML and XML files
#import pandas as pd             # Python package for data manipulation and analysis
import re                       # regular expressions
import json                     # Python package used to work with JSON data
#from tqdm import tqdm           # python for displaying progressbar
from datetime import datetime

url = 'https://www.imdb.com/chart/top'
url_text = requests.get(url).text
url_soup = BeautifulSoup(url_text, 'html.parser')
template = 'https://www.imdb.com%s'
title_links = [template % a.attrs.get('href') for a in url_soup.select( 'td.titleColumn a' )]

movie_names = []

for title_link in title_links:
    page_soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(title_link).text, 'html.parser')

    movie_names.append(page_soup.title.get_text(strip=True).split(' (')[0])


print(movie_names)
```